# Ruby class method naming conflicts

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Is it possible to use the method `open` on my `Parser` class? It seems that the method is conflicting with `IO::open`?

```
class Parser
    require 'nokogiri'

    def parse
        doc = open "someFile.html"
        # Get to parsin' ...
    end 

    def open str
        Nokogiri::HTML(open(str))
    end 
end 

parser = Parser.new
parser.parse
```

When I run the script I get this error:

```
$ ruby parser.rb
parser.rb:10: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

I've tried a variety of things, but the only thing that seems to work is to rename `Parser::open` to something other than `open`, like `docopen`

I'm trying to understand how ruby works, so any further explanation beyond the answer is **greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open` is a method on the module Kernel that is included in `Object` the parent class of all Ruby classes. What happens is that `open(str)` in

```
class Parser

  def open str
    Nokogiri::HTML(open(str))
  end
```

is calling your defined `open` method on Parser recursively. If you change your method to

```
  def open str
    Nokogiri::HTML(Kernel.open(str))
  end
```

you'll call the `open` method on Kernel as intended.

Comment: YES, that is right! Very informative. I did not know about the `Kernel` object

Answer (score 2):

What seems to be happening is that

```
def open str
  Nokogiri::HTML(open(str))
end
```

is in a recursive loop which just causes the `SystemStackError` making the stack level too deep.

What exactly are you trying to do with open(str)? When you changed the `open` to `docopen`, where exactly did you change it?

Comment: I renamed the `open` method on the `Parser` class from `open` to `docopen` here `doc = open` and here `def open`

Comment: Yeah, that definitely would do it. The `open`` inside the Nokogiri::HTML(open(str)) was calling the open method in Parse causing it to go into infinite recursion which causes the stack to overflow.

Comment: Another probable way to fix the issue would be to do something like this Nokogiri::HTML(IO::open(str)) to have ruby access the IO method instead of the Parse one.

Comment: Yeah, that brings another question. I tried `IO::open(str)` and then I get the error `TypeError: can't convert String into Integer`

Comment: So reading the docs, apparently IO.open takes the file descriptor as argument not the filename. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-new

Comment: That makes sense, I thought it might be something like that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are having a `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)` error because your method is beeing called recursively.

```
def open str
  Nokogiri::HTML(open(str)) # here you call this same method over and over again
end
```

This happens because the method you defined is more close in context so it's the one picked to be called.

You can just rename your method as you figured out or you can do something like this to explicit call it on one receiver that has the open method you want to use defined

```
def open str
  uri = URI.parse(str)
  Nokogiri::HTML(uri.open)
end
```